# LINK from Faucet not showing in my Metamask

Tags: wallets

Got successful transfer of 10 Link from the faucet but cannot see Link  in my Metamask Account.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to manually add the token to your metamask wallet.

1. In the assets tab, scroll all the way down and click `Import tokens`
2. Find out the contract address of the Link token depending on the chain you are using: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
3. Copy the address into the `Token Contract Address` and confirm

Answer (score 0):

The Rinkeby and Ropsten testnet explorers will be deprecated on October 5th, 2022.

[https://twitter.com/etherscan/status/1569311894279958531[![enter](https://twitter.com/etherscan/status/1569311894279958531%5B!%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvSwY.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvSwY.png)